# all pages redirecting too many time except home page (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

i have laravel webstie my web home page is working only all other pages redirecting too many times even it die; in the start of app/public/index.php 
not stopping . 
my myroot/public/.htaccess code is below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On



    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://self.phpavenue.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

please check the access code and help me 
thanks

Comment: Why are you not using the routes/web.php file? Change your last line of your .htaccess to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` and then create routes in the web.php file. All Laravel apps access index.php and then will go to a specified route. If you want to change base url, then you can do that in the .env file by changing `APP_URL` to `http://self.phpavenue.com`

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]` with following

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```